# How to get the original path of a portable Electron app?

Tags: electron, portable-applications

I have an Portable Electron App (packed with: electron-builder + asar, portable build) on Windows. I try to get the application path but it returns a path within the user\temp folder rather than the actual '.exe' file

Is there any way to get the original app.exe path?

I've tried the following:

- app.getAppPath()
- __dirname
- require.main.filename
- app-root-path
- and a few node modules

The path I'm getting from my tests:

> C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\xxxxxx.tmp\app

the actual .exe Path (where the app launched from, and what i need):

> C:\Users\XXX\Documents\test\dist

I'm just starting with Electron.

Comment: I collected some path data for windows and mac - see here https://github.com/BananaAcid/Simple-Electron-Kiosk/blob/master/PATH%20RESULTS

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a solution:
Use the Environment Variable (created by Electron-Builder)

```
process.env.PORTABLE_EXECUTABLE_DIR
```

to show the real Path of the App.exe.
Works only packed with Electron-Builder

Comment: I'm on mac right now where this is empty..tried it in dev mode and after building :/

Comment: on windows it seems to work..so maybe combining this for windows and the other answer (which isn't working as expected on windows) for mac and maybe linux which I still have to investigate
so who receives the bounty?

Comment: Out of curiosity is this environment variable set at all by a non portable build of the application? If not it would be a nice way for the app to be able to tell whether or not it was portable.

Comment: Does not work anymore! `PORTABLE_EXECUTABLE_DIR` is undefined

Answer (score 14):

From the main process:

```
// If not already defined...
const { app } = require ('electron');
const path = require ('path');

let execPath;

execPath = path.dirname (app.getPath ('exe'));
// or
execPath = path.dirname (process.execPath);
```

From a renderer process:

```
// If not already defined...
const { remote } = require ('electron');
const path = require ('path');

let execPath;

execPath = path.dirname (remote.app.getPath ('exe'));
// or
execPath = path.dirname (remote.process.execPath);
```

Comment: on mac it returns `../build/mac/APPName.app/Contents/MacOS`
which is not what we need...we could String.replace or String.split to get only the `...builld/mac` part, then it would be nice to programmatically know the app names of every build because windows and linux have version numbers (maybe I just construct it from the package.json) I'll check if it yields the same on windows and linux :-)

Comment: maybe a combination of your solution and the one from LycaKnight..but then who earns the bounty?

Comment: For me it returned `/Applications/Weaver.app/Contents/MacOS` and the path required was `/Applications/Weaver.app/Contents/MacOS/Weaver` with Weaver being the name of my app. My tests was requiring the path, and now the test does start an instance of Electron (Weaver)

Answer (score 6):

I had a lot of trouble with this and was finally able to solve the issue by replacing __dirname with '.', see working example below :

```
const path = require('path')
const myAppPath = path.resolve('.', 'myapp.exe');
```

Comment: It took me Hours to find this solution. Thanks

Comment: Spent 30 minutes searching multiple responses that made no difference. This is the only solution that has worked so far. Makes no sense that it's not in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `PORTABLE_EXECUTABLE_FILE` only works under certain Electron-Builder configurations; In particular, it won't work in apps deployed as a portable directory.

In such cases, the following will get you the application root path:

```
const path = require('path')
import { app } from 'electron'

let rootDir = app.getAppPath()
let last = path.basename(rootDir)
if (last == 'app.asar') {
    rootDir = Path.dirname(app.getPath('exe'))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked for me on Windows 10.

`process.env.PORTABLE_EXECUTABLE_DIR` returns the Temp directory path.

I got it to work using:

```
process.env.INIT_CWD
```

Answer (score 1):

```
process.env.PORTABLE_EXECUTABLE_FILE
```

will give you the full path to the file.

Comment: in my project `PORTABLE_EXECUTABLE_FILE` is undefined in DEV build. No idea why

Comment: It should be. You need to create the .exe file and then execute it for that variable to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

As none of the methods above worked and I don't want to use an external lib for this, i tried following:

```
        if (!fs.existsSync("../images")) {
            fs.mkdirSync("./../images");            
        }
        return path.resolve("./../images/") + "/";
```

You can use any directory that should exist at the top level or anywhere else. In my case I know that one level higher in the directory there must be a directory called "images".

This solution worked in my case for DEV build and prod (packaged).

Are there any drawbacks when using this approach?

Comment: The fact that you are creating a directory outside of your application? How do you know you even have the permissions to do so?