# Can't access user data path from render process electron

Tags: electron

I want to get the user data default directory of the application, i can get it from the main process easly but i can't access it from the render process. I have used the following for the render process based on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46564004/13958953) but it didn't work.

```
// If not already defined...
const { remote } = require ('electron');
const path = require ('path');

let execPath;

execPath = path.dirname (remote.app.getPath ('userData'));
// or
execPath = path.dirname (remote.process.execPath);//even this is returning the same error
```

it is giving me an error that remote is `undefined`. I have tried accessing the `app` directly like in the main process `app.getPath('userData')` but it is still returning the same error. Is there a way to access the `userData` folder path from the render process? or if there is a way to share it in a variable from the main process, it would be good.

I used `electron-app-settings` and set it in a settings promise but it is returning an object and i can't use it in the download function that follows:

```
 ipcRenderer.send("download", {
        url: "download url",
        properties: { directory: dir}
    });
```

The error that i am getting is: `Uncaught Error: An object could not be cloned. at EventEmitter.i.send (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:73)`
I am using `electron-dl`